# JSON deserialize throwing on error on deserializing an sObject

Tags: apex, json

I am trying to convert a sObject inside a JSON object. I have created a JSON structure using a class.

```
public class AccountData {
    Public List<AccountDataNode> AccountList;
}

public class AccountDataNode {
    public string AccountId;
    public Account fields;
}
```

There is an extra _metadata node in JSON fields section but I was hoping that it will not cause any issue as mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize)

> When deserializing JSON content into an Apex class in any API version,
> or into an object in API version 35.0 or later, no exception is
> thrown. When no exception is thrown, this method ignores extraneous
> attributes and parses the rest of the JSON content.

[image]

But when I run code that I have shared below it throws an error.

```
 String a = '{"AccountList": [{"Fields":{"__Metadata":{"test":"test"},"Name":"test"},"AccountId":"ID"}]}';
AccountData accountDataObject = (AccountData)JSON.deserialize(a, AccountData.Class);
```

> Expected AccountData.AccountDataNode but found null at [line:1,
> column:953

Is documentation wrong or I am missing something here?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Expected AccountData.AccountDataNode but found null at [line:1, column:953

Answer (score -1):

Solution to above problem is using `JSON.deserializeUntyped`.

Tried using below class structure but we can't use `JSON.deserialize` to `deserialize` a JSON into a generic object.

```
public class AccountDataNode {
    public string AccountId;
    public Map<String,object> fields;
}
```

Documentation is also partially correct. If we are converting JSON structure to `sObject` then we need JSON like `Map<String,String>` but in my JSON structure what we have is `Map<String,Object>`.

```
{"Fields":{"__Metadata":{"test":"test"},"Name":"test"}
```

will not work but below JSON will work

```
{"Fields":{"__Metadata":"test","Name":"test"}
```

So make sure JSON structure you are trying to convert to an `sObject` doesn't contain any Object as Value.